# Is there a tricky way to avoid overriding all pure virtual functions of template base class, used in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, member-functions

Pretty complicated (and bad) title, here's what I mean by example:

```
struct type1 {};
struct type2 {};
struct type3 {};

template< typename TYPE >
struct interface {
    virtual void f( TYPE ) = 0;
};

struct processor {
    template< typename TYPE >
    void f( TYPE ) {
        // something + for some TYPE-s have specializations, but it's irrelevant
    }
};

struct der: interface< type1 >, interface< type2 >, interface< type3 > {
    processor p;

    void f( type1 t ){ p.f( t ); }
    void f( type2 t ){ p.f( t ); }
    void f( type3 t ){ p.f( t ); }
};
```

Is there any tricky way to avoid all overrides in `der`? In the real case, `der` inherits `interface` 10 times (with different template types and it could be extended in the future). And it's rather ugly to have 10+ overrides of `f` when their bodies are the same.

`processor` could be changed to anything, also `der::p` could be some container, holding a `template`-d `processor`, etc.

It sounds like I want to have a `virtual template` member function `f`, which is not allowed.

I thought about using a macro, but I don't like that idea.

**EDIT** Note: can't use c++11, unfortunately. And can't change `typeN` types, which are not in hierarchy.

Comment: Create base type for `type`s and inherit from `interface<baseType>` I guess...

Comment: I should have mentioned that - I can't change `typeX` and they are not in hierarchy. But still, can't imagine how this will help. I'll think about it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, if they aren't in hierarchy, this idea is not worth pursuing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## C++03 solutions

(See KerrekSB's answer for solutions using C++11 features)

You can use another layer of inheritance and CRTP to dispatch the calls to your processor:

```
template< typename TYPE, class ProcessorHolder >
struct processorDispatch : interface<TYPE> {
    virtual void f( TYPE t ) override {
        processor& p = static_cast<ProcessorHolder*>(this)->p; //CRTP --> explicit downcast
        p.f(t);
    }
};
```

And use it as

```
struct der: processorDispatch< type1,der >, processorDispatch< type2,der >, processorDispatch< type3,der > {
    processor p;

  //make f visible - either
    using processorDispatch< type1,der >::f;
    using processorDispatch< type2,der >::f;
    using processorDispatch< type3,der >::f;
  //or
    template <typename TYPE>
    void f(TYPE t) {
      processorDispatch<TYPE, der>::f(t);
    }
}

};
```

---

A take at Kerrek's non-CRTP-solution, but "C++11-free" vía base class chaining:

```
struct der_base {
  processor p;
};

template <class TYPE, class Base = der_base>
struct der_t : Base, interface<TYPE> {
  void f(TYPE t) { this->p.f(t); } 
  using Base::f;
};

template <class TYPE>
struct der_t<TYPE, der_base> : der_base, interface<TYPE> {
  void f(TYPE t) { this->p.f(t); } 
};
```

And then use

```
typedef der_t<type1, der_t<type2, der_t<type3> > > der;
```

Comment: Hm, I'll try that, too. Sounds good. I guess `override` is not essential in this case? I can't use `C++11`, unfortunately.

Comment: Ou, the "C++11-free non-CRTP" solution would make the usage horrible, when you have 10+ types, but I get the idea, thanks! But are you sure about the `processorDispatch` way? Because `type1 t1; der d; d.f( t1 )` gives me ambiguous call.

Comment: @KirilKirov I fear I left the using directives that are mentioned in the comments on Kerrek's asnwer. That's of course unfortunate.

Comment: @KirilKirov if you have many interfaces to inherit, you can also write a template function that explicitly calls the corresponding dispatcher's `f` (see my edited code). However, that one does not allow for implicit conversions, e.g. a call `d.f(42)` will give a compile error if you have inherited only from `processorDispatch<long,der>`, since `42` is int.

Comment: @KirilKirov the base class chaining solution needs using directives, too. I added it, including a specialization needed because `der_base` does not have `f`.

Comment: Cool, the solution with additional template function in `der` works great! That's what I needed. Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: In case you're still interested in this, I posted my own question, a slight modification of yours, which simplifies a bit the things. I won't change the accepted answer, as it's still your idea, a bit changed.

Answer (score 5):

You could make `der` a template:

```
template <typename ...> struct der;

template <> struct der<>
{
    processor p;
};

template <typename Base, typename ...Rest>
struct der<Base, Rest...> : der<Rest...>, interface<Base> 
{ 
    void f(Base x) { this->p.f(x); }
};
```

Then use:

```
der<type1, type2, type3> d;
```

---

Here's an alternative design using CRTP:

```
template <typename Actual, typename Base> struct FImpl : Base
{
    void f(Base x) { static_cast<Actual*>(this)->p.f(x); }
};

template <typename ...T> struct der : FImpl<der, T>...
{
    processor p;
};
```

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that without variadic templates.

Comment: Hm, can this be implemented without variadic templates?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think you should be `using der<Rest...>::f;` within `der<Base, Rest...>`, otherwise the remaining `f`'s from other bases would be hidden rather than overloaded, right?

Comment: @iavr: I was wondering that, too, but for the purpose of using the classes through their polymorphic bases it shouldn't make a difference. Also, in the CRTP alternative, you'd need a variadic using declaration :-)

Comment: @KirilKirov: I provided a non-variadic approach of Kerrek's first solution in my answer.

Comment: @ArneMertz - I saw, thanks both of you, +1 from me, I'll see which one will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, similar to @ArneMertz 's one, could be (**but** it involves several instances of `processor` - one per type, so could be inappropriate for some cases):

```
struct type1 {};
struct type2 {};
struct type3 {};

template< typename TYPE >
struct interface 
{
    virtual void f( TYPE ) = 0;
};

template< typename TYPE >
struct processor 
{
    void f( TYPE t ){ std::cout << typeid( t ).name() << std::endl; }
};

template< typename TYPE >
struct interface_impl: interface< TYPE >
{
    processor< TYPE > p_;
    void f( TYPE t )
    {
        p_.f( t );
    }
};

struct final: interface_impl< type1 >, interface_impl< type2 >, interface_impl< type3 >
{
    template< typename TYPE >
    void f( TYPE t )
    {
        interface_impl< TYPE >::f( t );
    }
};
```

---

This is almost the same, with one difference only - `processor` is added in the "middle" class. In terms of @Arne's answer:

- make `processor` template class
- `processorDispatch` has a member `processor` with the same `TYPE`

This:

- eliminates the `static_cast`
- simplifies the inheritance (one type vs two)

---

Or even `processor` could be defined inside `interface_impl`, like

```
template< typename TYPE >
struct interface_impl: interface< TYPE >
{
    struct processor 
    {
        void f( TYPE t ){ std::cout << typeid( t ).name(); }
    } p_;

    void f( TYPE t )
    {
        p_.f( t );
    }
};
```

Comment: Well thats a different thing - the templated instances of `processor` are now three different object, not sharing internal state. All the solutions above try to deal with the fact that you mentioned only a single processor object in the question ;-)

Comment: Well, I have this in my question `processor could be changed to anything, also der::p could be some container, holding a template-d processor, etc`, but maybe it wasn't clear enough. It doesn't really matter, just wanted to share one more way. Thanks anyway, you helped me a lot :)